# how to give a pre-defined value to TexareaField?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm new here
I'm just trying to give a value to a text area field in flask-wtforms
in text field i only should use`value="blah blah"`
so anything about text area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample from documentation

```
def edit_article(request):
    article = Article.get(...)
    form = MyForm(request.POST, article)
```

Can be rewritten as

```
def edit_article(request):
    article = Article.get(...)
    data = request.POST or {}
    data.setdefault('fieldname','default value')
    form = MyForm(data, article)
```